# Setting var on success

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have this code, the alert works pefectly and returns the correct value grom the php file, but the Var is always undefined:

```
var NombreUrl;

function marck(id) {
  $.ajax({ 
    data: { id_propiedad: id },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",  
    url: "/ajax/armarURL.php", 
    success: function(respuesta) {
      alert(respuesta);
      NombreUrl = respuesta;
    },
    error: function(respuesta) {
      NombreUrl = 'error';
      //alert('no');
    }                                       
  });
  $( "#listado" ).append( '<li id="marca'+id+'"><a href="'+NombreUrl+'">test</a></li>' );
}
```

The php file is returning this:

```
$nombreURL = 'test.php';
echo json_encode($nombreURL);
```

im having an alert whit "test.php" but the NombreUrl var is undefined.
any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The `$.ajax()` operation is **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous. You need to move your line that starts:

```
$( "#listado" ).append( '<li id="marca...
```

into your success function, like so:

```
success: function(respuesta) {
  alert(respuesta);
  NombreUrl = respuesta;
  $( "#listado" ).append( '<li id="marca...
},
```